# Arc length formula

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Does $f'(x)$ have to be continuous in $[a,b]$ in order for $L=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\, dx$ to work? My textbook assumes $f'(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ in the proof of the formula.

If $f'(x)$ has to be continuous in $[a,b]$, then how can we find the arc length of $f(x)$ in $[a,b]$ if $f'(x)$ is not continuous in $[a,b]$?

Comment: Take a look at the derivation of the arc length formula. It is essentially the Pythagorean theorem on differentials, i.e. $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2\implies ds^2=1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 dx$. That is not rigorous but that is the idea. So if the derivative was not continuous you should be able to find a point along the curve where that expression for $ds$ does not work.

Comment: @JohnDouma It seems you have some typos in the formulas.

Comment: Not after you take square roots. Take a look at this paper: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/506-S12/506-1.pdf It has examples of pathological curves.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The $dx$ after the square of the derivative should be squared. The differential form of this is only a mnemonic. It illustrates that you are taking the limit of small polyonal lengths.

Comment: @JohnDouma It should be $ds^2=\left(1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)dx^2$.

Comment: Of course. Either way, check out the paper. I do believe we need continuity.

Comment: @JohnDouma The 'arc length' of $f(x)$ is defined for all continuous functions $f(x)$. Can't we find the arc length of any continuous function $f(x)$? Is there a method to find the arc length of $f(x)$ no matter what the continuity of $f'(x)$ is?

Comment: A space filling curve is continuous everywhere, differentiable nowhere and has infinite arc lengh. So, no, we cannot define the arc length for all continuous functions.

Comment: @JohnDouma Can't we claim an infinite arc length is still defined, just infinite?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It's required to have $f'(x)$ be continuous if we **always** want this arc length formula to work.

In fact from a theorem,

"If $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, or if $g$ has only a finite number of jump discontinuities, then $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$; that is, the definite integral $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$ exists."

That is, we require $g$ or in your case, $\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$, to be continuous to avoid inconsistent results.

Another theorem,

"If $h$ is differentiable at $a$, then $h$ is continuous at $a$."

So, we know $\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}$ is continuous on all $\alpha$ in the real numbers, hence $\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$ will be continuous wherever $f'(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: We don't _require_ it by the theorem, the theorem only says it's sufficient.

Comment: The theorem says "if $g$ is continuous or with finitely many discontinuities in $[a,b]$, then $g$ is integrable in $[a,b]$", not the other way around.

Comment: @user263326 Yes you're right! It is sufficient that $f'(x)$ be continuous otherwise you end up with inconsistent results, whether you get false/absurd results, 1=0, or whatever else. Unless proven otherwise.

Comment: @Areayouheaty Read the theorem again: "_if_ $g$ is continuous or with finitely many discontinuities in $[a,b]$, _then_ $g$ is integrable in $[a,b]$". Using this, we cannot claim anything of the form "_if_ $g$ is integrable, then $\ldots$". The theorem says nothing about the latter sentence.

Comment: @user263326 I'm aware. When did I ever mention the latter holds?

Comment: So i.e., using the theorem you gave, you cannot claim anything of the form "in order for the integral to exist, it's necessary that $\ldots$", so we can't claim it's necessary that $f'(x)$ is continuous. The word "_always_" doesn't change this.

Comment: @user263326 Well I don't imagine the arc length formula giving a consistent result if $f'(x)$ is discontinuous over an interval and your limits of integration cross over this interval. In what sense do you mean by "for the arc length formula to work?" Is it the right result? Is it that you don't get division by zero? I can integrate $1/x^2$ from $-1$ to $1$ and ignore the premise that $1/x^2$ be continuous, I still come out with a finite value.

Comment: In the Theorem, in what sense do you mean "integrable"? Do you mean Riemann integrable?

Comment: Because if you mean "Riemann integrable", then I have a stronger theorem: "bounded $g(x)$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ if and only if $g(x)$ is continuous [almost everywhere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostEverywhere.html)" (theorem found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Discontinuity.html)).

Comment: @user263326 Yes I mean Riemann integrable. Are you familiar with improper integrals? I'm under the impression that $f'(x)$ need not be discontinuous on the whole interval $[a,b]$ (otherwise this is silly), improper integrals will attempt to evaluate arc lengths for functions $f(x)$ that are discontinuous at some intervals/points within $[a,b]$.

Comment: Indeed it's simple to handle this with improper integrals if the number of discontinuities of $f'(x)$ is finite. Not so sure about an infinite number of discontinuities.

Comment: This answer has the implication reversed. Lots of functions have discontinuities but are integrable and $\sqrt {1+f'(x)^2}$ can be one of them.Consider a function $f$ that is piece-wise linear, or the function $f(x)=\sqrt {1-x^2}$ for $x\in [0,1]$.